# Java constant String gets corrupted in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, mobile, mobile-devices

I'm collecting data from users' devices for analytics. I've got some final static Strings representing event names (e.g. "**banner_click**"). As the appropriate event occurs the event name gets stored in sqlite database, after which I periodically read them from DB into JsonObject and make HTTP request to send the collected data to our server, but sometimes we get corrupted event names ("**banner_clÄ±ck**" instead of  "**banner_click**", "**i**" is replaced with "**Ä±**" in all such cases). This case happens rarely, but it worries me. So I'd like to know how come constant string be corrupted, I cannot reproduce it myself. My only guess for now is that it's a device specific issue.

Answer (score 4):

The `i` in your `click` is actually `ı` i.e. LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I. The UTF-8 for it is `0xc4 0xb1` and interpreting those bytes as ISO-8859-1 gives the `Ä±`.

1. Fix the character to be a regular `i`.
2. Mind your character encoding when dealing with non-ASCII.

Comment: Exactly how should I fix the character to be regular i ? I just have class with defined String constants. And why doesn't it happen constantly if there's a such issue?

Comment: You most likely have the dotless i somewhere in your code.

Comment: You described the most probable case, but I cannot find any dot less "i" in my code I don't know how I could even type that. I'm checking my keyboard's "i" and it gets interpreted like "U+0069" which is normal dotted lowercase "i".